# Android Libgdx How to keep aspect ratio of background image?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx to create a game for android. If I want to set the background as an image that fills up the whole screen, how can I keep the aspect ratio of the image? I don't want remaining blank space or letter boxing, but if you set the image size as the whole screen, it is going to stretch on some devices and it will look distorted...

Comment: Have you tried using [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)?

Comment: @ashebar which one is better for this? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it? How? Thanks